# Windows 10 Logins and shared resources not functioning

Tags: networking, vpn, login, shared-folders, windows-server-2016

(Actual IPs and Server names have been removed and replaced with examples)

Point 1:
We can not login to the domain unless we remote connect to the server and login, `There are no login servers available`.

Point 2: I can not access shared resources on `\\SERVERNAME\`,  but if I connect over the VPN we have setup (`\\10.0.0.2\`). We get the error

`\\SERVERNAME\ is not accessible. You might not have permissions to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of is server to find out if you have access permissions.

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.`

So what do I do, kinda stuck in a weird position of everyone not being able to sync their files, and not being able to use work accounts on their PCs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted the issue, I just realised I added it as a network controller.

(If you have a similar issue):

Try demoting it from a network controller, use another machine if you really need one.

1- Open the server manager

2- Head to Tools > Remove Roles and Features > Next > Role Based > Pick the affected server > Remove Network Controller and RSAT

3- Hit remove

4- Restart the machine